# ffmpeg command line help

Tags: video, ffmpeg, jpeg, flv, conversion

Does anyone know how to use ffmpeg?

i got a list of files (video1.jpg, video2.jpg ... video10.jpg) that i want to convert to a .flv file so it displays like a slideshow. Does anyone know the command line statement for that?

i'm currently running on ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past is...

```
ls *.jpg > files.txt
mencoder -nosound -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4 -o test.avi -mf type=jpeg:fps=20 mf://@files.txt
ffmpeg -i test.avi test.flv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`ffmpeg -f image2 -i video%d.jpg video.mpg`

Scanged from http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs.